# Dropdown validation using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am using AngularJs. I have a dropdown in which I want to do validation on click of submit button. The dropdown is defined as below:

```
<select name="userTypeSelect" ng-model="selecteduserType"  ng-options="user.UserTypeName for user in users" ng-change="updateImageUrl(selectedUserType)">
    <option value="">-- Select the User --</option>
</select>
```

The submit button is defined as below:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="add()" />
```

The option `-- Select the User -` is the first option available in dropdown. I want to check if user does not select anything or selects `-- Select the User --`, I want to show a validation on click of submit button.

How to check if dropdown has proper data, not empty when user clicks on submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this working demo it will work as per your expectations.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'user1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'user2'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'user3'
      }];
    $scope.add = function() {
      console.log("submitting");
    };
    $scope.changeOption = function() {
      $scope.submitted = false;
    };  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && add()" novalidate>
    <span ng-show="submitted == true && myForm.userTypeSelect.$error.required">User type select is required.</span>
    <select name="userTypeSelect" ng-model="selecteduserType"  ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in users" ng-change="changeOption()" required> 
        <option value="">Select Service</option> 
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true"/> 
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: HI.. On indexxhange, is it possible to hide the error message and only show when submit button is clicked

Comment: @venkat14 It is working on submit only..on indexxhange error message is already hide.

Comment: Hi. indexchange the error message is getting visible. scenario: Initial message is hidden. select service and click submit. Message is shown. Now select a valid data. And again select "select service", the error message is shown

Comment: Ok got it. I updated the answer as per your expectation. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Just check `$scope.selecteduserType.length` in if condition

```
$scope.add(){
    if($scope.selecteduserType.length){

    }
    else{
        alert("pls select a value");
    }
}
```

OR

```
<form name="myForm" >
    <select name="userTypeSelect" ng-model="selecteduserType"  ng-options="user.UserTypeName for user in users" ng-change="updateImageUrl(selectedUserType)" required> 
        <option value="">Select Service</option> 
    </select> 
    <span ng-show="myForm.userTypeSelect.$error.required">Select service</span>
    <input type="submit" ng-disable="myForm.$invalid" value="Submit" ng-click="add()" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `required` to the `<select>` and then Angular will validate that an option besides the default with no value is selected. Here's a simple example to show it in action:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'First Option'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Second Option'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Third Option'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        text: 'Fourth Option'
      }, {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Fifth Option'
      }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
    <div>
      <select name="select" ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option as option.text for option in options" required>
        <option value="">--Please select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="form.select.$invalid && form.$submitted">Please make a selection</div>
    <div>
      Selected option is valid: {{form.select.$valid}}
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried this, Only on submit button click event, the error message should show. Also, initially when the option is "--Select User-- " , then the error message should not show.